# Distance between two sets $X$ and $Y$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact and closed subset of a metric spaces $M$ respectively, then prove that $\inf\ \{d(x,y)|x\in X, y\in Y\}=d(x,y)$ for some $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$.

I am just here to verify my proof. Please help if I am wrong.

**Proof:**

Let $f:X\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be the distance function from $Y$ defined by $f(x)=\inf\ \{d(x,y)| y\in Y\}$, then $f$ is a continuous function. Also, $X$ is a compact set so $\min_{x\in X} f(x)=f(x_1)$ for some $x_1\in X$. Hence, $\inf\ \{d(x,y)|x\in X, y\in Y\}$ $=\inf\ \{d(x_1,y)|y\in Y\}=d(x_1,y_1)$ for some $y_1\in Y$ as $Y$ is closed.

Comment: Seems correct to me

Comment: You asserted without proof that $f$ is continuous. Unless you have that as a previous result, I would view that as a major gap.

Comment: Your proof is correct except that there is no justification of why $f$ is continuous.

Comment: You may want to add that $X,Y$ should be non-empty

Comment: It may be faster to argue that $d\colon M\times M\to\Bbb R$ is continuous  attains its minimum on the compact(!) $X\times Y$.

Comment: Can you please explain it? @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: I believe Hagen von Eitzen was fooled by the clumsy wording of the conditions into thinking $Y$ is compact as well. In general $Y$ simply being closed is not enough to guarantee that $X \times Y$ is compact. For example $[0,1]\times[2,\infty)$ is not compact.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I must disagree. Your proof doesn't work, and the reason is that this "theorem" as stated is false.

Let $X = [0,1], Y = (2,\infty)$ and $M = X \cup Y\subset \Bbb R$. $X$ is compact, and $Y$ is closed in $M$. Then $d(X, Y) = 1$, yet there is no $y\in Y$ such that $d(X, y) = 1$.

In addition to the issue that Hagen von Eitzen pointed out (it also fails when $X$ and $Y$ are empty), the problem with your proof is that you simply assumed that $Y$ being closed was enough to claim $y_1$ existed.

(The function you defined earlier is continuous, so that is not a problem with the logic, though the commenters are correct that unless it had been proven elsewhere, you need to prove it here.)

The correct result must assume that $Y$ is compact as well.